# Python3 Unicode Character Space

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, utf-8, utf

So I'm trying to find a way for python3 to tell me how much space a character takes up
I have found a method that works for some characters, it looks like this

```
from wcwidth import wcswidth
length = wcswidth('ひ')
```

But this doesn't work with some characters, ones like this
﷽
is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Basically, no. `wcwidth` is intended to tell you whether a given character takes up zero, one or two character positions in a fixed-width font. The "character" (which is really a composite of several characters rendered as a ligature) which you tried is probably not going to be present in a fixed-width font (which means that your font manager may try to find an alternative font to use to render it).

Comment: The task you are asking is very difficult: it depends on the font, the language, and nearby characters. And next character may be put nearer (look e.g.: AV, vs. AA or VV). So usually you render it in a buffer and ask for the displacement. (you are lucky that some font tools are written in python (and open source))

Comment: I recommend this article : [Text rendering hates you](https://faultlore.com/blah/text-hates-you/). It dives into why your question is much more difficult than you may expect.